# How to create choices on the fly using autocomplete-light in django

Tags: jquery, django, widget, on-the-fly, django-autocomplete-light

I am able to get auto-complete working.

**django-version : 1.8**

But i also want to create choices on the fly, and these choices should be saved in `Tag` model.

According to my understanding, `remote.js` is to be used.
Hence I have added the below snippet to `autocomplete_light_registry.py` : 
 `'data-bootstrap':'rest_modal'` 
`'autocomplete' : 'remote'`

the below `remote.js` snippet is also being fired

```
$('body').on('initialize', '.autocomplete-light-widget[data-  bootstrap=rest_model]', function() {
    $(this).yourlabsWidget(yourlabs.RemoteAutocompleteWidget);
});
```

But still, the `getValue` function of `remote.js` is not being called

**models.py**:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**:

```
autocomplete_light.register(Tag,
    search_fields=['name'],

    attrs={
       'autocomplete' : 'remote',
       'placeholder': 'Please enter related tags?',
        'data-autocomplete-minimum-characters': 1,
    },
    widget_attrs={
        'data-bootstrap':'rest_modal',
        'data-widget-maximum-values': 4,
        'class': 'modern-style',
    },
)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class DocUploadForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        # widgets = {'tags' : autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceWidget('TagAutocomplete')}
        autocomplete_fields = ('tags',)
        exclude = ['organization','private_user']
```

What am i missing here ?

Do ask, if more clarity is required in the question or in the code

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remote.js is not necessary here.

1. Implement object creation in your [Autocomplete.post()](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/example_apps/create_choice_on_the_fly/autocomplete_light_registry.py)
2. Use your own [JS to trigger it](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/example_apps/create_choice_on_the_fly/static/create_choice_on_the_fly/fly_widget.js)

Example app: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/autocomplete_light/example_apps/create_choice_on_the_fly

Live Example: http://dal-yourlabs.rhcloud.com/admin/create_choice_on_the_fly/